# jquery map array returning NaN in iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse this array of checkbox values and remove the "N".

Using the replace function yields the error *TypeError: numberArr[i].replace is not a function*, and if I remove the replace function, the script simply outputs *NaN* for my values.

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/j0w5tkg9/3/

```
<div id='opts'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-cost="0" value="44N12345" name="options[]">
    <input type="checkbox" data-cost="0" value="55N6789" name="options[]">
</div>
<div id='output'></div>


 function getAllocArray() {
     var numberArr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function (e, i) {
         return +e.value;
     });
     var varOutput = '<ul>';
     for (var i = 0, len = numberArr.length; i < len; i++) {
         varOutput += "<li>" + numberArr[i].replace(/N/,'') + "</li>";
     }
     varOutput += '</ul>';
     $('#output').text(varOutput);
 };

 $('#opts').on('click', 'input:checkbox', null, getAllocArray);
```

Comment: In our case you can use `parseInt(+e.value)` instead of `+e.value`. `parseInt('44N12345')` returns `44`, but `Number('44N12345')` returns NaN because there is string `N`

Comment: The attempt to convert something like "44N12345" to a number by prefixing it with a `+` operator is what's giving you `NaN`.

Comment: And why not return the LI elements in the mapping instead of iterating over the same thing twice ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j0w5tkg9/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not convert value to `Number`. Replace `+e.value` to `e.value`:

```
 var numberArr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function (e, i) {
     return e.value;
 });
```

Numbers does not have [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now !  ;-o    Just need to wait the mandated 11 minutes to accept your super-quick answer ! THANK YOU !